# Android Layout: Can't place the elements where I want

Tags: android, layout

Hi all 
I was wandering if there was a easy way to do the following without android layout
place an image central top
place a button center center
place a button left bottom
place a button right bottom

it doesn't sound that difficult no ?

well I can't figure out a way to place the elements as I want using stupid xml layout

can somebody help me out here ?

cheers

Jason

Comment: First of all, the XML layout can't be stupid and second there is something called punctuation use it for the readers sake. Please reformat your question so we can actually understand it.

Comment: clear your question i can't figure out what exactly you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).

Comment: I actually had to go for a more complex solution and create my own view and draws because other of my views weren't possible with any form of layout ^^

Comment: The relative layout is the most flexible layout I could find yet it is not adequate. You cannot place elements were you want them/ I've found both the size and position of each element is restricted based on the position of other elements.

Also if one element changes size another element aligned to it will also change.

Comment: @JasonRogers Have you found a more elegant solution since now and your last comment? It's sad how complez this is compared to apples nib files.